# Scaling problems with Android geny emu vs preview, pics included, is dp right unit to use?

Tags: android, scale, genymotion

Hi i get this problem on the genymotion emulator where everything is way smaller than on the preview.  The emulator is a Custom Phone 5.1.0 API22 768x1280 with 160dpi.  Since i use dp shouldnt everything scale appropriately so it looks like the Android Studio preview? i dont understand whats going wrong.  Thanks for any tips

[image]

Comment: 768x1280 @ 160dpi = 4.8in x 8in  It is a tablet. You were probably looking for something more like 768x1280 @ 320dpi.

Comment: thanks i think i get it now

Answer (score 1):

In the android studio simulator the devices is not scaled to the physical size of the real devices. and that also applied for the preiview.

I think this is also the case in the Genymotion Emulator.

What you pointed is right. using the dp works as you described,

Comment: but even relatively everything is way smaller within the screen of emulator, almost like a tablet or something, if i were to add more rows or columns to a list/gridview there would be many more shown in the emulator than in the preview or real S5, i do not have this problem on S5

Comment: as you can see in the pic the emulator window is even BIGGER than the preview, yet everything inside is SMALLER than in the preview